# How to improve the performance of TensorFlow inference?

Tags: python, tensorflow, inference

I wrote a script to identify objects in JPEG images using TensorFlow. I found that the Inference stage took a long time to complete. Here are the related codes:

```
N_CHANNELS = 3
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    """
    Converts a PIL image into a numpy array (height x width x channels).
    :param image: PIL image
    :return: numpy array
    """
    (width, height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()) \
        .reshape((height, width, N_CHANNELS)).astype(np.uint8)

def process_output(classes, scores, boxes, category_index):
    """
    Processes classes, scores, and boxes, gathering in a list of ObjectResult.
    :param classes: list of class id
    :param scores: list of scores
    :param boxes: list of boxes
    :param category_index: label dictionary
    :return: list of ObjectResult
    """
    results = []

    for clazz, score, box in zip(classes, scores, boxes):
        if score > 0.0:
            label = category_index[clazz][NAME_KEY]
            obj_result = ObjectResult(label, score, box)
            results.append(obj_result)
    
    return results

# Inference
tic = time.perf_counter()
IMAGE_NP_KEY = 'image_np'
RESULTS_KEY = 'results'

file_result_dict = {}

for filename in TEST_IMAGES:
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(Image.open(filename))
    
    output_dict = run_inference(graph, image_np)
 
    results = process_output(output_dict[DETECTION_CLASSES_KEY],
                             output_dict[DETECTION_SCORES_KEY],
                             output_dict[DETECTION_BOXES_KEY],
                             category_index)

    file_result_dict[filename] = { IMAGE_NP_KEY: image_np, RESULTS_KEY: results }
toc = time.perf_counter()
print("Inference completed in", round(toc - tic, 2), "seconds")
```

It took **222.91** seconds to analyze 10 JPEGs (each less than 2MB). How can I improve the script's performance?

- TensorFlow version: 1.14.0
- CPU: 3.6 GHz 10-Core Intel Core i9
- AMD GPU (Radeon Pro 5700 8 GB) is not supported by TensorFlow
- RAM: 16GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- Operating System: macOS 12.4
- running in Conda environment (not sure if it's related)

p.s. Other parts of the codes are also available on request. Thanks.

Comment: A reproducible example would be helpful, but I am sure you know that.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/shivanraptor/object-detection/tree/main